# Is multi-threading or asyncio suitable for receiving real time tick with API requests and at the same time perform other tasks

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, time-series, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have python function which receives and store live tick data from a server(By API requestes). And another function which fetch the data to candle bars of 1minute and appends it to pandas Data frame. Then i want to call another function which apply some mathematical computations and manages order execution in live market.

But i am confused in which method to use between Multi-threading, Multi-processing or AsyncIO. What i want is uninterrupted flow of tick data which receives data in fractions of milliseconds to my system so that i donot miss any realtime data, And at the same time able to manage orders and perform mathematical computations.

Please advise me which option will be better to choose from the above?

Comment: How about not using Python?

Comment: Why not just run two separate applications?

Comment: By separate application do you mean multi processing or two entirely different systems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use multi-threading and/or asyncIO since getting processes to work together can be a pain in the neck. Since you need to do computations, you should store the data/use a queue and use a *second process* to make the calculations,and you can add more math processes if one couldn't catch up with data inflow.
On second thought. You'll still have to carefully pack data fast enough so you don't spend most of your time transferring the data(`pickle` or process `Queue`s don't work 'cause they're too slow)you'll need some custom way, say `structs` to quickly pack and unpack the data.
But at that point, you might as well use C/C++ as your second(math processing) process :)

TL;DR: Use `ansycio` and/or `threading` to receive data, custom `structs` to quickly pack/unpack data, and a few other Python/C/C++ etc. processes to retrieve and process the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to add a few "Can multi threading handle ticks data of more than 100 symbols per second uninterrupted and at the same time able to perform other tasks?"

Comment: This depends on what you mean by 'other tasks', if you mean things like doing '.lower()` and `.upper()` on them, yes. If you mean splitting and uploading, maybe.If you mean dumping it into something like PyTorch, Defiently no.

Comment: By other tasks i mean calculating moving averages, making support and resistance lines and managing portfolios etc. Then i guess i should go with asyncio. Which can handle such tasks easily.